# Help for wind noise

Tags: noise, wind

Does anyone in the forum have experience with anything that can block the noise of wind that doesn't look like I have fur growing out of my ears?

Comment: Could you be a bit more exhaustive, please? Tell us what you have tried already, why it didn't work, if there are any restrictions beside not looking like furry ears...

Comment: Surely the problem with this is that if you block the noise of the wind, you also block the noise of traffic? Or are you in a traffic-free environment?

Comment: I really only have the problem when I have the helmet straps over my ears.  I adjusted the straps so the straps straddle the ears rather than covering them

Comment: another forum mentioned a review on bikeradar, read it and don't want that fuzzy look   still looking for something more refined

Comment: I am the owner of Cat-Ears, LLC. We make wind noise reduction products for cyclists (the ones with fur). This post/question is by the owner of our competition, based in Oregon. This person has posted the same or similar questions on numerous forums, all around the 20th of February, on the same date they joined the forum. This person also signs up under different names (JohnAndrews508; MarkJones300; Uberbikegeek, etc) and, if their product doesn't get mentioned, they will respond under another new member name to their own question, mentioning their own product. This person has inundated forums

Comment: @PeteH Cat Ears don't exactly block wind noise, they prevent the noise creation which would otherwise happen as the wind flows past your ears and becomes turbulent.

Answer (score 2):

I used cat ears until they were stolen, along with my helmet. I really liked them. I found that they reduced the amount of stress that persistent noise can cause, and I felt safer because I was able to hear everything a lot more clearly. No, not paid by the company, just honest.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you could try.

A simple headband over your ears would be an easy an cheap solution.

In case you don't want anything to fully cover your ears you can buy ear plugs designed specifically for this purpose.

Google: blocking wind ears cycling

And you get plenty of options.

www.cat-ears.com for example.

Of course. Good in ear monitors work also on case you want to listen music while riding.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was hoping to find folks with experience with something other than fuzzy pads that look like Elvis sideburns or an 80 year old man with hairy ears.  :)   There are some others out there--look more high tech. Comparison?